# DataFrame. Split Column to antoher Columns with average by date

Tags: pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe:

```
d = {'date' : ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02'], 'type' : ['Bird', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'], 'weight' :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to split the "type" column by the value of type and get columns - Bird, Dog, Cat. And values in these columns must be the average weight of the birds, dogs, etc. on the same date.

To get something like that.

```
date        bird     dog      cat
2020-02-01  ...      ...      ...
2020-02-02  ...      ...      ...
```

I started to try group by but can't figure out with that. Maybe split dataframe by val in the "type" column and merge the obtained dataframes again?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_table` and apply `mean` to aggregate values those has the same index/column:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='type', values='weight', aggfunc='mean') \
        .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output:
         date  Bird  Cat  Dog
0  2020-02-01   2.5  3.0  2.0
1  2020-02-02   7.0  6.0  5.0
```

Comment: What the type is mean in your last table? It looks like an index.

Comment: `type` is the name of column axis like `date` is the name of index axis. I updated my answer to get exactly your output